# inner join (on join time i want replace salash(/) with dot(.)

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Whenever i am using inner join the some problem is coming.

**Inner Join Query**

SELECT DISTINCT dbo.SEWER_LINE.OBJECTID, dbo.SEWER_LINE.Pipe_ID
FROM  dbo.SEWER_LINE
```

INNER JOIN dbo.Division ON dbo.SEWER_LINE.Division =   dbo.Division.Div_ID
INNER JOIN dbo.WWS_ZONES ON dbo.SEWER_LINE.Zone_ID = dbo.WWS_ZONES.ZoneID

```
**One Table is :**

**select Div_ID from Table Name Division**
Div_ID is Store Like This :       **GOAPWD/DIV/III**

And Table Name SEWER_LINE         **GOAPWD.DIV/XXI**

On My Inner Join Query i want change result 

 **GOAPWD/DIV/III**  First (/) Salash Remove with Dot(.)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SUBSTRING(FIELD, 0, CHARINDEX('/', FIELD)) + '.' + SUBSTRING(FIELD, CHARINDEX('/', FIELD) +1, LEN(FIELD)-CHARINDEX('/',FIELD))